# Loop never starting

Tags: java, for-loop

I am trying to write a small method which will calculate the exponent given a number and power (I know about math.pow I am just doing this for kicks). However the loop inside my method never starts and I cant figure out why. My code is below, all help appreciated.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

int result = exponantCalculation(2, 3);

System.out.println(result);

}

public static int exponantCalculation(int number, int power) {
    for (int i = 1;i >= power;i++) {
        number = number * number;
    }
    return number;
}
```

Comment: `i <= power` (your loop would only be entered if `1` is `>=` `power`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You've used the wrong comparison operator in the loop condition (`>=`, should be `<=` or `<` — see other answers).
2. Not sure, maybe this was intentional, BUT if the method is meant to calculate "`number` to the power of `power`", then you're incorrectly **squaring the result of the previous iteration**. This will produce a much higher value that the `number` to the power of `power`.
   You need to introduce a new variable and multiply it with `number` in the loop, e.g.

   ```
   long result = 1;
   for (int i = 0; i < power; i++) {
       result *= number; // same as "result = result * number"
   }
   return result;
   ```

   *Minor note:* I've intentionally used `long` type for the result, which can *slightly defer* the integer overflow problem for big values.

Comment: As Dawood mentioned, it needs to be "< power", since it shouldn't go into the loop if power is just 1.

Comment: Thanks @DawoodibnKareem, I've been uncareful. Corrected this; and now the power of 0 is also correctly calculated.

Comment: Looks much better now.

Answer (score 1):

Condition inside `for loop` is wrong.

Since you are passing `3` as `power` in your method as parameter, `i` is initialized with `1` and then condition gets checked whether `i>=power` with is obviously not true in this case so your loop never starts.

Change

```
for (int i = 1;i >= power;i++)
```

to

```
for (int i = 1;i <= power;i++)
```

if you wish to calculate the power of any number, you can use following method

```
public static int exponantCalculation(int number, int power) {

      int result = 1;
      for (int i = 1;i <= power;i++) {
          result = result * number; 
      }  
      return result;
}
```

Comment: With your solution the the code inside the loop will be executed but the answer won't be 2^3

Comment: @karolovbrat see the complete method i wrote in my answer that will work with my solution

Comment: yep, that looks better :) Do you really need the first part of the if statement when power == 0?

Comment: yeah right. Completely overlooked the fact that `result` is initialized with `1`. edited...

Answer (score 0):

The for loop condition was wrong, but also you need to sotre the result in another variable:

```
 public static int exponantCalculation(int number, int power) {
    if(power == 0){
      return 1;
    }
    int result = 1;
    for (int i = 1;i <= power;i++) {
        result *= number;
    }
    return result;
}
```